# How to move rows from one worksheet to another if they contain a key word

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with many data points and several columns.
I want to automatically copy rows from one worksheet into another if the columns `Q:V` contain the word `"sold"`.
Below I have my first stab at the code - it was unsuccessful.
Thank you in advance for the help!

```vb
Sub IntiveResponse()
'Used to filter participants based on key word sold
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim A As Long
    Dim B As Long
    Dim C As Long
'Change primary workbook name below
    A = Worksheets("162545-response-export").UsedRange.Rows.Count
'Change output workbook name below
    B = Worksheets("Invited").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If B = 1 Then
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Invited").UsedRange) = 0 Then B = 0
    End If
    Set xRg = Worksheets("162545-response-export").Range("Q:V")
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For C = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(C).Value) Like "Sold" Then
            xRg(C).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Invited").Range("A" & B + 1)
            If CStr(xRg(C).Value) = "Done" Then
                C = C - 1
            End If
            B = B + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: "unsuccessful" could use a little more detail - did you get an error, or what happened which was not what you wanted?

Comment: Maybe you wanted `If CStr(xRg(C).Value) Like "*Sold*" Then` if you need to match "sold" within other text.  FYI it's bad practice to adjust the For loop counter `C` within the loop. Also comment out that `On Error Resume Next` and see if anything changes.